# "НА целом свете" или "В целом свете". Как правильно и есть ли разница?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, выбор-слов, значение-слов, предлоги

*Но если ты меня приручишь, мы станем нужны друг другу. Ты будешь для меня единственный **в целом свете**. И я буду для тебя один **в целом свете**...*
[Антуан де Сент-Экзюпери. Маленький принц](http://www.vavilon.ru/noragal/pp/pp21.html) (перевод Норы Галь)

***На целом свете*** хлеба нет вкусней,
Чем выпеченный матерью для сына...
[Расул Гамзатов](https://books.google.ee/books?id=oKdgBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&lpg=PT68&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=44CY80HLMu&sig=lCBHCyPhGEcUMqfoB1IWpuq6MM8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBkKPgv-_cAhULyKQKHSRHCA84ChDoATADegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5&f=false) (перевод Я. Козловского)

Есть ли между этими выражениями смысловая (или какая-нибудь другая) разница?
Как определить — какое из них нужно использовать?
(Мне ближе "на целом свете".)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

В «Большом универсальном словаре русского языка» под ред. В. В. Морковкина указываются лишь сочетания ***во** всем свете*, ***в** целом свете*. В этих сочетаниях *свет* — это земля со всем, что на ней существует; т. е. мир. (Ср.: ***во*** всем мире, но не ****на*** всем мире.)

Различие между предлогами *в* и *на* может быть описано таким образом: предлог *в* указывает на пребывание *внутри* чего-нибудь, а *на* — на пребывание *на поверхности* чего-либо или на направление движения на поверхности предмета. В ряде случаев эти различия размыты, ослаблены и не ощущаются. В таких случаях выбор предлога либо несущественен, либо определяется традицией. *(Словарь грамматических вариантов (ИРЯ РАН).)*

По распределению соответствующих вариантов в НКРЯ видно, что наиболее распространена конструкция с предлогом *в*. Видимо, это стоит признать своего рода традиционным употреблением. Тем не менее, на мой взгляд, нет существенных оснований полагать использование в данном словосочетании предлога *на* неверным в какой-либо степени (ни в стилистической, ни в грамматической, ни в лексической). **Предлоги *на* и *в* в этом случае взаимозаменяемы.**

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю в качестве расширенного комментария цитату из работы доктора филологических наук М.В. Всеволодовой "Способы выражения пространственных отношений":

> Примечание: Группа **в мире** является нормой для литературного языка и обязательно в таких сочетаниях, как: *первый в мире, лучший в мире, самый высокий в мире, единственный в мире* и т. п. Группа **на свете** чаще встречается в поэзии и в разговорной речи. Сочетание **целый свет** может выступать с предлогом в: **в целом свете.**

Answer (score 0):

*В целом свете* - пространственное представление о мире,  *на целом свете* -  его плоскостной  вариант (на свете - на земле).

Вероятно, сначала светлый  мир представлялся трехмерным, судя по большей частотности употребления этого сочетания.

*На целом свете* - более современное выражение. Оно уже не метафорическое, как раньше (свет -  добро, а тьма -  зло), а просто отражение обычной семантики предлогов В и НА: В - внутри предмета, НА - на его поверхности).

Answer (score 0):

Практически полные синонимы. Здесь "свет" - синоним "мира" (в смысле "вселенная"), но сравните: на свете - в мире. Отсюда и колебания.